# How to set value in unique row-column in c# list view?

Tags: c#

I am using c# list view to show tabular information. i am adding list view items as follows:

```
this.listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("A");
 this.listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("B");
  this.listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("");
```

This is working and adding the values for the first row randomly . I mean A in column 1 , B in column 2 and nothing in column 3.
What i need is that, I want to add the values in the column for a particular index. For ex. I only want to add the value in row 1 and column 2.
How?

Comment: First you say you want to add items randomly. Then you say you want A in col 1, B in col 2, null in col 3. That's not random. If you want to set values to a subitem of index eg. 3, can call or set it with eg`this.listView1.Items[0].SubItems[3] = new ListViewDataItem("test");`

Comment: Use `Insert` instead of `Add`